# Vim closing a file with defaults

Tags: vim

Is there a way to tell Vim what to do every time I'm about to close a file? Specifically I am asking because I don't want to make a call to `:mkview` all the time, especially since I forget it most of the time...
So can I tell Vim to call `:loadview` when I open a file and `:mkview` when I close it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answers are often in Vim's help, if you know what to search for. In this case, one possible solution is at [`:h :loadview`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/starting.html#%3aloadview):

```
To automatically save and restore views for *.c files:
    au BufWinLeave *.c mkview
    au BufWinEnter *.c silent loadview
```

You can modify this to suit your own needs. To make it apply to all filetypes, use `*` instead of `*.c`. To make this happen at Vim startup and exit, use the events `VimLeave` and `VimEnter` instead of `BufWinLeave` and `BufWinEnter`.